# Using the nb.control argument of glmer.nb

Tags: r

I am working on a negative binomial model using the `glmer.nb` function within the `lme4` package of R. The actual model itself is somewhat complicated, but should be (at least I believe) statistically sound. My question at the moment arises because the model is having difficult converging and returns this warning:

`In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00753068 (tol = 0.001, component 1)`

Most of the time, I work within the standard `glmer` function, and there, when I get this warning, I add this argument to the `glmer` function:

`glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000))`

That usually solves the problem. Now, looking into the help file for `glmer.nb`, it appears the analogous argument for `glmer.nb` is `nb.control`. However, when I just change `glmerControl` to `nb.control`, R returns an error that it can't find that function. Ok, that's fine. From the given syntax in the help file, it looks like `nb.control` is supposed to be set equal to a list of whatever your desired control arguments are. I have tried various ways to get my two desired changes, and R just keeps dropping `nb.control` with the warning "`extra argument(s) ‘nb.control’ disregarded`"

I have tried searching the vast resource that is the internet for an example of someone that has used the `nb.control` argument. Most things that I have found (and I haven't been able to find much, hence this question) seem to just recommend the use of the `glmerControl` argument from `glmer`. When I put that argument in, it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Essentially, I am just wondering how to use the `nb.control` argument to change the optimizer to 'bobyqa' and change the number of iterations to a higher number than default. What is the syntax for using the `nb.control` argument when it is not the defauilt value of `NULL`? Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's a little counterintuitive, but you should use `control=glmerControl(...)` for this, just as you would for the analogous `glmer` fit - this will get passed through to the inner loop.

Set up data etc:

```
library(lme4)
dd <- expand.grid(f1 = factor(1:3),
                  f2 = LETTERS[1:2], g=1:9, rep=1:15)
dd$y <- simulate(~f1+f2+(1|g),
                 newparams=list(beta=rep(1,4),
                                theta=1),
                 newdata=dd,
                 seed=101,
                 family=negative.binomial(theta=1.5))[[1]]
```

Fit "vanilla":

```
m.nb <- glmer.nb(y ~ f1+f2 + (1|g), data=dd)
```

Check optimization info:

```
m.nb@optinfo[c("optimizer","control")]
## $optimizer
## [1] "Nelder_Mead"
## 
## $control
## $control$verbose
## [1] 0
```

Fit with alternative optimizer/etc.:

```
m.nb2 <- glmer.nb(y ~ f1+f2 + (1|g), data=dd,
                  control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",
                           optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e5)))
```

Check that we actually changed something:

```
m.nb2@optinfo[c("optimizer","control")]
## $optimizer
## [1] "bobyqa"
## 
## $control
## $control$maxfun
## [1] 1e+05
## 
## $control$iprint
## [1] 0
```